# How to change the price filter in Blueprint BigCommerce

Tags: php, bigcommerce

Can anybody tell me which file we need to change the price filter?

Right now it has by default min and max price filter, but I need the list type price filter.

Comment: Nah............

Comment: Your urgency is not a factor and no excuse for not providing a valid [mcve] so create one ASAP

Comment: Would you please stop to edit “urgent” back in? This is NOT urgent to anyone else here, and if it is to you, then feel free to go and get paid support somewhere. Otherwise, show some patience, like everybody else here has to.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "price type"?
In the meantime, there is a way to add additional filters to a blueprint theme. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/legacy/blueprint-themes/product-filtering-toolkit

Comment: @T.J ,I am asking that right now in my blueprint bigcommerce theme my price filter is like( min- max update) but i want my filter like this ($5-$10,$10-$15,$15-$20) like this. is there a way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To enable product filtering, which includes shop by price, on a BigCommerce store it must be on a Pro or Enterprise plan. After that, you can use the following guides to customize and manage the product filtering.

https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Product-Filtering-Settings
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/legacy/blueprint-themes/product-filtering-toolkit